# Why doesn't base64_decode return false on invalid input?

Tags: php

```
echo base64_decode("http://www.domain.com/en/messages/list?all=1");
```

this gives the result:

```
†Ыiяь0БЪ&j)ЬўoЮџщћІЖ zПеЉЛZ–]
```

How to check if `string` is `base64_encoded` ?

Shouldn't it return `false` if it's not valid base64 encoded string?

I have some urls base64_encoded comming from emails and some simple urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do `base64_decode("http://www.domain.com/en/messages/list?all=1", TRUE);`

The `,TRUE` puts it in "strict mode".  Which means it will return `FALSE` if the string contains invalid characters.

Comment: Thanks you. Didn't noticed that flag there.

Answer (score 3):

It is not mathematically feasible to automatically detect, for *all* inputs, whether they were intended to be a base64-encoded version of something else.

The input you show is *valid* base64 data, whether you intended for it to be used that way or not.

You can mitigate things slightly by setting the second parameter to `TRUE` so that non-base64-alphabet characters in the input cause an error. But you could still have an input with only characters found in the base64 alphabet, which wasn't originally designed to be interpreted that way. There's simply no way to know for sure without some metadata.

Answer (score 0):

The only time the base64_encode returns false is when the input contains characters that are not in the base64 alphabet.

[See the wiki on base64 alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)